# Is there an attribute that captures the ordering of the data in a bokeh DataTable?

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

Is there an attribute of bokeh.models.widgets.tables.DataTable, or the underlying ColumnDataSource, that indicates the order of the data? I would like to have the columns of a bar chart reorder when the table is sorted by clicking on the column headers, but I can't find any attribute that I can use to trigger the figure update.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets.tables import DataTable, TableColumn
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.io import curdoc

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'y': [1, 2, 3]})

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

my_table = DataTable(source=source,
                     columns=[TableColumn(field=x, title=x) for x in 
                              source.column_names])

my_figure = figure(x_range=source.data['x'])
my_figure.vbar(x='x',
               top='y',
               width=0.9,
               source=source)

l = layout([my_table, my_figure])

curdoc().add_root(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

In BokehJS there is `renderer.view.indices` and `renderer.view.indices_map` where renderer is a glyph object. There should be some equivalent in Python. The `indices_map` contains information to which values from `data_source.data` the indices are mapped FWIW.